# How do you place text underneath and over an operator simultaneously?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

So as know, `$\underset{i = 1}{\bigcup}$` is how you place text *under*  an operator.

And `$\overset{n}{\bigcup}$` is how you place text *over* an operator.

But how do you combine the two? I've tried things like `\underset\overset{i=1}{n} \bigcup` as well as `$\underset{i=1}\overset{n} \bigcup$` but those are syntactically incorrect.

**Main question: Basically, I want a union symbol with its initial index as *i=1* and its ending index as *n***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting the union of sets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205125/formatting-the-union-of-sets)

Comment: In display math, `\bigcup_{i=1}^n` already sets the subscript/superscript below/above the operator.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote,

> So as know, `$\underset{i = 1}{\bigcup}$` is how you place text under an operator.
> And `$\overset{n}{\bigcup}$` is how you place text over an operator.
> But how do you combine the two?

`\bigcup` and `\bigcap` are defined as variable-sized math operators. This is, incidentally, also the case for `\sum`, `\prod`, and `\int`. Hence, placing subscripts and superscripts is no different than for `\sum`, `\prod`, and `\int`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n$ \quad $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n$ \quad $\bigcup_{i=1}^n$

$\displaystyle\bigcap_{j=1}^M$ \quad $\bigcap\limits_{j=1}^M$ \quad $\bigcap_{j=1}^M$

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^K$    \quad $\sum\limits_{k=1}^K$    \quad $\sum_{k=1}^K$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for `\smashoperator` from the package `mathtools` and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\smashoperator[l]{\mathop{=}_{sub}^{sub}}
\]
\end{document}
```