# Subscripts in \sup not on desired position

Tags: amsmath

For

```
\sup_{\varrho_{i}, \forall i}
```

I get
[image]

What should I change such that I have this subscript exactly under sup?

Comment: If you're using `$\sup...$`, then use `$\displaystyle\sup...$` instead.

Comment: You might use `\sup\limits_{\varrho_i,\forall i}` but you'll spoil the distances between base lines.

Comment: For a similar situation, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205125/4427 and answers thereon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have subscripts below `\sup` at in-line math gives ugly result:

[image]

so I strongly discourage to use it on such a way. At display math is different story. There this is standard way to write `\sup`:

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % not needed for reproducing your problem
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
I get $\sup\limits_{\varrho_{i}, \forall i}$ \lipsum[11]
\begin{equation}
\sup\limits_{\varrho_{i}, \forall i}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```