# Why \bigcup appears too small

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In `\begin{align}` or `\[\]`, `\bigcup` or `bigwedge` appear in normal size. However, in regular math-mode, they appear the same size as `cup` or `wedge`. The sample code is:

```
$X\in V_{\alpha}=\underset{\beta<\alpha}{\bigcup}V_{\beta}$
```

I wonder what is the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: You have to remember that inline maths is supposed to be used ... well ... inline. As a consequence it is more economical with space especially when it comes to line height. If it weren't it would cause irregular line spacing. You could go full `$X\displaystyle\in V_{\alpha}=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}V_{\beta}$` but for *real* inline maths that probably results in bad typesetting. Is there no option of making this a display formula if you insist on big symbols?

Comment: For the same reason (bad line spacing) I would avoid a construction like `\underset{\beta<\alpha}{\bigcup}` in inline maths, which appears to be a way to work around the more space-saving default behaviour of `\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}` in inline maths. (I think the more classical way to force the display-style behaviour of limits in inline maths is `\bigcup\limits_{\beta<\alpha}` instead of the `\underset` trick.)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205127/4427

Comment: `\bigcup` is usually larger than `\cup` even in inline mode but it  depends on the fonts, about which you have given no infomation. `\underset` can't really be used in inline math though it is more or less _not_ inline by definition.

Comment: @moewe, thanks. `\displaystyle\bigcup` works. Sometimes, big font for certain symbols are needed in inline math mode, i.e. numerical list and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When you put single $ around the math equations, you are putting them inside the in-text math mode, which are smaller than the display mode. If you want to force a display size in the in-text environment, you can use the \displaystyle command.